# How to map many-to-many association to a class mapped to two different tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a Voucher - POJO mapped to two tables. The first mapping assigns an entity name "voucherA" and maps the POJO to TableA. The second mapping uses "voucherB" as entity name and maps the POJO to TableB.

Now i have also a customer POJO mapped to TableC. This POJO references vouchers in a list.

```
<list name="vouchers" table="TableC_vouchers">
  <key column="pid"/>
  <list-index column="position" base="0"/>

  <!-- how to do that right -->
  <many-to-many column="voucher_id" entity-name="voucherB"/>
</list>
```

How do i properly map a list of many-to-many associations from customers to vouchers so that if a customer POJO is persisted, the Voucher entities are persisted to TableB if they don't exist there, instead of TableA? Can this be done? If not, what would a workaround look like so that vouchers used by customers are persisted to tableB? (TableA contains only available Vouchers, not the used ones)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you stuck using a table for each kind of voucher? Would it be unacceptable to store the two types vouchers in a single table?

Comment: The second table schould contain only those vouchers that have been used. Also in my case, one voucher can be used multiple times by different users. In my question TableA can be unserstood as "Vouchers still available to be used" and TableB "Vouchers that have been used". It also can happen that vouchers from TableA get deleted. I'm stuck how to create the many to many association.

Comment: I see. Would it be unacceptable if you stored a flag in the table for each voucher which would be true if the voucher is used and false if not. I think this way you could still delete unused ones at will, but you could have all vouchers in the same table, which makes many-to-many trivial.

Comment: my preference would be the two table soultion, but if this is not possible or too complicated to implement i will go for a one table soltion

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I do think this is the simplest route. You can find my "official" answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your core model seems wrong. Your `Voucher` entity presumably has many attributes - do ALL of them change after it's used by a `Customer`? I doubt that. And yet, you're duplicating them in your A and B tables which means your schema is not normalized.

"Available" voucher and "used" voucher are not (or should not be) the same entity. I would instead suggest that you create a new entity for `UsedVoucher` that would link to both `Voucher` as  many-to-one and `Customer` as many-to-one and contain only "changed" properties of `Voucher` (if any). So,

```
Voucher(id, other attributes) // doesn't change from what you have now
Customer (id, other attributes) // doesn't change except for many-to-many; see below
UsedVoucher(id,
 voucher, // what Voucher was used by that customer
 customer, // what Customer has used that voucher
 changed voucher attributes, // if any
 additional attributes // if needed, such as date/time when voucher was used
)
```

Your "many-to-many" on `Customer` will become "one-to-many" (collections of Vouchers used by this customer) IF you need it as maintainable property; otherwise it's easily retrievable via query.

You can't physically delete from `Vouchers` table under this scenario, though (unless Voucher in question was never used). You'll have to do a logical delete instead.

Comment: I agree with your answer. Just as an aside, it is sometimes legitimate to choose to have a denormalized schema. With Hibernate, the design in code heavily influences the schema. Your problem could be such that it is easier to do something if you use table-per-subclass inheritance. Making that choice often means you are going to be duplicating data. I would therefore stop short of saying the model is "wrong".

Comment: Lyudmil - there are different kinds of denormalization, some more acceptable than others. In this case, though, based on my understanding of what OP wanted (and he hasn't been very clear, to be fair) I would most definitely advice against bundling everything in one table. You'll end up with "base" voucher and **multiple** "claimed" vouchers together, resulting in inability to have any meaningful FK / business key constraints. Besides, I said "**seems** wrong" :-) - again, based on my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to store all vouchers in the same table. To distinguish between used and unused ones you could either have a boolean flag or a discriminator value (if you're using inheritance in your Java code).

Even if you have existing data it does not seem like the migration would be terribly difficult. Once all vouchers are in the same table, their relationship to customers becomes a straight-forward many-to-many.

I think maintaining two tables would be difficult. Essentially, you're still storing whether a voucher is used or not, but you're not doing it explicitly. I'm sure there could be a workaround, but I think what I've outlined above is much simpler. In my experience, this is the route I have chosen every time when faced with a similar problem.